# UIViewController LifeCycle

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

I just tried some stuff using View Controller delegates and learn about their functionalities. There is one thing I would like to try:

I wrote a function to unwind programmatically a viewController by using the segues. The views are inside a navigationViewController. Additionally I set a instance var inside my destination VC by using:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "unwindToRootSegue" {
        let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController
        destinationController.callLaunched = true
    }
}
```

I then wanted to check if the value has been set in the destination VC. And thought of using the `viewWillAppear` function. But this has no effect. What method should be used to be notified when the view I am rolling back to (the destination VC of the segue) has been loaded/is displayed to perform further action.

My goal is, to perform an action when the instance var has been set to true. So my idea was, to check for the instance var as soon as the destination view has been loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use an unwind segue, you start by setting up a method in the destination view controller.

```
@IBAction func unwind(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    // unwind
}
```

Note, that this method is placed in the **destination** view controller.  The view controller being unwound to.

From here, we need not the segue's `destinationViewController`, but instead the `sourceViewController`.

```
@IBAction func unwind(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    if let source = segue.sourceViewController as MySourceViewController {
        self.someProperty = source.someOtherProperty
    }
}
```

But if we just want to do something once we unwind here no matter what, we can ignore the `segue` altogether (looks like what you're essentially doing there except for thinking you need a reference to the `destinationViewController`):

```
@IBAction func unwind(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    self.callLaunched = true
}
```

Comment: thank you nhgrif. And how do I find out that the unwind has been completed so I can call another function?

Comment: This is similar to a normal segue.  It just depends.  You can call another method within this `unwind` method if you want.  Or you can wait until `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`.  Just depends on what you're trying to accomplish.  It's important to note that `viewDidLoad` won't be called.